# Pegar valor de botão em js

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tentando pegar o valor de um botão e colocá-lo numa variável, mas não dá de jeito algum, alguma ajuda?

```
///HTML
<button class="teclado" id="qTeclado" onClick="clickTeclado(this.value);" value="Q">Q</button>
//JS
var letra = function clickTeclado(letra) {
document.getElementById('qTeclado').onClick = letra;
alert(letra);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estás a misturar um bocado o código, é mais simples:

```js
function clickTeclado(letra) {
  alert(letra);
}
```

```html
<button class="teclado" id="qTeclado" onClick="clickTeclado(this.value);" value="Q">Q</button>
```

Ou seja: a função `clickTeclado` tem de ser declarada, e depois passas o `this.value` como argumento. Assim, dentro da função, já tens o valor que queres no parâmetro `letra` da função. Neste cado não precisas do `id` do botão pois estás a chamar a função diretamente no `onclick` com o valor.

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @PauloHenriqueRodriguesGrund se a resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 